# Laravel sail how to remove created application

Tags: laravel, wsl-2

I created a new laravel app

```
curl -s https://laravel.build/example-app | bash
```

then I removed all files from the directory where I created it

then I tried to install it again with the same code and get an error

```
 Cannot create project directory at "/opt/example-app", it exists as a file.
```

But I don't see any file in /opt

Please advise how I can remove it completely

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried stopping the container first?

```
./vendor/bin/sail down
```

or from docker desktop app.

Answer (score 0):

Try to see if there are any hidden files.  Go into the folder in question and show hidden files.  On mac it would be

shift-cmd-.

Answer (score 0):

I tried removing Docker images and volumes. In the end, a restart of Docker Desktop solved this issue for me.

Solution from:
https://www.reddit.com/r/laravel/comments/lgc6h9/cannot_create_project_directory_it_exists_as_a/